# Statements after IF condition running before IF block executes

Tags: jquery

I have rows to delete, deactivate or mark as read. Now for delete and deactivate, I show a warning with a bootbox modal window while the 'mark as read' needs no warning. There are three buttons that are fired with the classname of `mass`:

```
$('.mass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr("data-action");

    // see action and warn as necessary.
    var goon = false; // decided to use goon to see if execution should continue or not, after my attempts without it failed
    if (action == 'delete') {
        //warn
        bootbox.confirm('Sure Delete?' function(choice) {
            goon = choice; //will be false or true
        });
    } else if (action == 'deactivate') {
        bootbox.confirm('Deactivate?', function(choice) {
            goon = choice;
        });
    } else { // we don't need warning
        goon = true;    
    }

    alert(goon); // to see
    if (goon == false) {
        return false;
    }
    //continue to server processing her
});
```

Now the problem is `alert(goon)` is fired before/when the modal window is displayed before `cancel` or `ok` are clicked. It is always `false`. The whole `if` block seem to have no effect. Once Cancel or Ok is clicked, it no more runs because already the process has been done.

What I am missing please?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed as you don't do anything with the returned value from the bootbox. Instead you immediately check `goon` (which will always be in its default state of `false`) and continue on.

To fix this you can extract your logic out to a function which is only called when the bootbox has been interacted with. Try this:

```
$('.mass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr("data-action"); 

    if (action == 'delete') {
        bootbox.confirm('Sure Delete?' function(choice) {
           choice && performAction(action);                
        });
    } else if (action == 'deactivate') {
        bootbox.confirm('Deactivate?', function(choice) {
           choice && performAction(action);   
        });
    } else {
        performAction(action);  
    }
});

function performAction(action) {
    // continue to server processing her
}
```

Comment: thanks. I never knew that way. newbie, thanks a lot. Will try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

never used bootbox, but from their from their documentation:
http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html

```
bootbox.alert("Your message here…", function(){ /* your callback code */ })
```

javascript is async, your code does not "wait" before it's executed.

I guess what you want to be doing is move the IF to the callback block.
that way it will be evaluated when the alert is closed.